# Is there any plausible astronomical source of energy that could wipe out humanity without rendering the planet inhabitable?

Tags: galaxy, space, life

I'm aware of hard radiations from space can wipe out life but I believe that would also causes the planet to be inhabitable for a period of time. Is there any other kind of energetic astronomical event that could destroy life through a transient pulse of radiation (particles or photons) without any "cool down" needed for new life to develop?

The event could be known or theoretical or just plausible that spans entire galaxy if necessary.

Comment: This question may be better suited to [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'm going to make a post there as well.

Comment: @CuriousSmith Please do not crosspost between different SE sites. The question will be moved there if necessary.

Comment: Do you mean *un*inhabitable—that is, incapable of being inhabited?

Comment: (at) CuriousSmith I've assumed you meant an astronomical event producing some energetic transient that kills everyone, but leaves the planet able to support a (probably much smaller) group of humans (or similar) if they then came to Earth soon after. Please double check if that is the question you want to ask in Astronomy stackexchange. You can ask a different question in Worldbuilding, but like @SirCumference says, please don't post the same question in two stackexchange sites at the same time. That's considered a no-no.

Comment: An asteroid wiped out the dinosaurs and any other large animals, but some life did survive.

Comment: Since life could exist elsewhere it is possible that a large comet could crash into earth which was contaminated by a virus that killed humans and other primates or closely related mammals.

Answer (score 1):

The cockroach and the tardigrade can withstand just about anything.  Next, any radiation blast consisting of wavelengths reasonably attenuated with water wouldn't affect, directly at least, all the deep-sea creatures.